# Can my post be reopened now?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

[Deriving life expectancy from FLIPI index data for FLIPI(3) High Risk](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/30788/deriving-life-expectancy-from-flipi-index-data-for-flipi3-high-risk)

Answer (score 3):

[The question you cross-posted](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/565141/deriving-life-expectancy-from-flipi-index-data-for-flipi3-high-risk) to Cross Validated received what appears to be a very good answer. You posted the following comment on that answer:

> I think that this was the answer that I was looking for. I have at
> least two years left instead of the 11 months of my prior simplistic
> analysis. Thanks for your help !

Thank you for providing an excellent example of why depersonalizing medical advice questions doesn't change them. Your comment makes it abundantly clear that the question was personal medical advice from the beginning and it remains personal medical advice even after your depersonalization.

This actually happens a fair amount. People post a question asking about a personal medical issue, the question gets closed, they edit it to remove personal details, and then expect it to be reopened because they camouflaged the real intent.

In American vernacular that's called putting lipstick on a pig. Nothing has changed about the question. The goal is still to obtain medical advice from strangers on the internet, which this site has voted multiple times that it will not provide. The StackExchange corporation has also decided the same thing, which it makes abundantly clear in the sidebar.

The personal details aren't the problem; you can broadcast your medical history all you want. In fact, many questions begin with people's personal medical issues but then proceed to ask an objective medical science question about it. That's perfectly fine. What you can't do is ask us what to do about it, ask us for a prognosis, or ask for a second opinion. The reasoning behind that is very clearly explained in [this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor/748#748), which everyone who has a question closed for that reason is given a link to.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's start with some context to all be on the same page.

The [first revision](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/revisions/30788/1) of this question seemed very clearly to focus on personal medical advice:

> Translating FLIPI index overall survival rate to months of life expectancy
> Translating FLIPI index overall survival rate to months of life expectancy
>
> Please refer to Table 5
>
> I was diagnosed as (3) high risk 2019-12-19
>
> FLIPI index(3)
>
> 5-year overall survival = 53%
>
> 10-year overall survival = 35%
>
> Here is my own estimated analysis FLIPI(3) years of survival
> 0.53 * 5 = 2.65 years
> 0.35 * 10 = 3.50 years
> (2.65 + 3.5) / 2 = 3.075 years from 2019-12-19
>
> FLIPI Calculator

In my opinion, that question was correctly closed as off topic (disclaimer: I voted to close at that time).

The most [recent revision](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/revisions/30788/7) now is mostly a question about survival analysis. This is a question which seems on topic on Cross Validated. The question author appears to agree, since they [cross-posted the question there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/565141/deriving-life-expectancy-from-flipi-index-data-for-flipi3-high-risk). The question received a helpful answer from a user there.

As noted on the main Meta site question [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

> As a general rule: **No.**
>
> Ask the question on the site you think is most applicable.

Thus, I think the question should remain closed as the question author received a useful answer on Cross Validated.

If the question were *only* asked here, I might argue that it is now potentially on topic for this site under the [on-topic section](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> • diagnostic and prognostic methods

To me, survival analysis seems like a "prognostic method."

As an aside, this question was reopened and migrated to Cross Validated. This is not the ideal situation, as the question already existed there. (I've certainly cast the binding vote on migrations that already existed, so no judgement from me.) The question is now closed as a duplicated on Cross Validated.

Comment: I just want to know whether or not my computation of how long I have to live is correct mathematically and medically. I had originally thought that I only had 11 months left. My oncologist simply didn't know enough math to give me an answer.

Comment: Yes, polcott, this is *exactly* why it was off-topic in the first place. We can't be offering you medical advice for all the reasons listed in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor/748#748).

Comment: The generic question provides the same answer and applies to everyone with a FLIPI(3) score. People really need to know these things.

Comment: Although the math part of the question is best answered by math people I still really need to know whether or **Average years of survival weighted by deaths per year** is a reasonable statistic for life expectancy. Now that I recalculated it median years to death comes up with a similar number:  5.81 (the number of years it takes for half of the 484 patients to die).